# Embedding a html website gives me "support.google.com refused to connect."

Tags: php, html, embed

When I try to embed this website http://testscib.unaux.com/form.html to another website through HTML with this code
`<embed type="text/html" src="http://testscib.unaux.com/form.html" width="500" height="200">`
It gives me this error.
"support.google.com refused to connect."

[image]

The button is also linked to a PHP file.

Comment: The unaux.com server does not allow that. `HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden`

Comment: Is there a way i can allow it as I own the both websites?

Comment: Yes, if you own them both then look at the settings on the one you are trying to embed. Also likely should use `iframe`, not embed. But thats not current issue

Comment: Please check whether CORS is disabled in the target server

Comment: Among other issues stated in comments, your site needs to be `https` just as the embedded google site.